# how to quit t-sql script if a result is returned from a table

Tags: sql

I'm putting together a sql script.  Basically half way through the script I want to check a table for the existance of any rows based on an EventID number.  In theory there shouldn't be any results returned but if there is I want to quit the remainder of the script and perhaps display an error message.

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set that query result to a variable and use if/else logic on the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RETURN` or use a `GOTO` to jump to the end.  If this is in a stored procedure then `RETURN` would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE EntryID = 1234)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Some error message', 16, 1)
END
```